# Performance counter is not added or deleted?

Tags: .net, windows, iis-7, performancecounter

**Hi,**

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7 that runns the following code on startup :

```
    if ((_UsePerformanceCounters = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsePerformanceCounters"])))
    {
        col = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
        counter = new CounterCreationData(_acountOfCurrentUsersCounterName, "Amount of current users", PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItemsHEX32);
        col.Add(counter);

        if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(_categoryName))
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(_categoryName);

        if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(_categoryName))
            category = PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(_categoryName, "MyApp Application Service Counters", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, col);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Counter already exists");

        if (PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(_acountOfCurrentUsersCounterName, _categoryName))
            _amountOfCurrentUsers = new PerformanceCounter(_categoryName, _acountOfCurrentUsersCounterName, HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~"), false);
    }
```

I can see that the category is removed and added everytime but I can´t still see it in the performance monitor?

It did showed up once but even when deleting and Exists = false the counter remaind as it looked before? After the weekend it has disappeared?

Is the performancemonitor unrealible? Is there some other software I should use? Or what Iam I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a refresh problem, I need to restart Performance Monitor to clear the cache.